# Paypal api error code 10007 - Permission denied - You don't have permission to make this api call

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated paypal express checkout to my client's website usi paypal api integration. It is working fine with sandbox environment. But I got error when I make it live. The error code 10007 - Permission denied - You don't have permission to make this api call. I am not sure why this is happening. I have configured everything perfect on seller paypal account. I didn't get any solution anywhere to solve this problem. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: basic though sometimes missed : have  changed the API credentials pointing to LIVE API credentials ? also, the API Endpoint point to LIVE

Answer (score 0):

`Basic though sometimes missed` :

- Have you changed the API credentials pointing to LIVE API credentials ?
- The API Endpoint point to LIVE ->https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp

Still issue persists, raise a ticket to [Paypal MTS team](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/).